# Nested resources without controller names in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, device

I've got a very simple Rails 3 app with a User model run by Devise and a Notes model. Right now the url and routing looks like this:

```
# url
/users/MEMBERNAME/notes/TITLE-OF-NOTE

# routing
resources :users do
  resources :notes
end
```

But I would like the urls to look like this, how would the routing look like in this case?

```
# url
/MEMBERNAME/TITLE-OF-NOTE
```

**Update:**

Thanks, now I discovered a new problem though. In my forms I have this code:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @note]) do |f| %>
```

and in my controller I redirect like this:

```
format.html { redirect_to([@user, @note], :notice => 'Note was successfully created.') }
```

In both those cases when I use @user, @note the old urls are still present. Do you know how to translate the form and the redirects to use the member/title structure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a custom route here:

```
get "/:user_id/:id", :to => "notes#show", :as => :short_user_note
```

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

To use the newly created named route:

```
# => /USER_NAME/NOTE_NAME
redirect_to short_user_note_path(@user, @note)

# => /user/USER_NAME/note/NOTE_NAME
redirect_to user_note_path(@user, @note)
# OR
redirect_to url_for([@user, @note])
# OR
redirect_to [@user, @note]
```

So, the general rule is if you pass an array of active_record objects like below to #redirect_to, #url_for or #form_for methods, the #polymorphic_url method is called internally, and generates the standard RESTful route.

Answer (score 6):

You can the routes behaviour you're after with working route helpers in Rails 3 with like the following:

```
resources :users, :path => ''
resources :users, :path => '', :only => [] do
  resources :notes, :path => '', :except => [:index]
end
```

See my [blog post](http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-3-nested-resource-slugs) for the details on how I arrived at this solution.